# How to connect data points (dots) by lines on ALREADY existing curves in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have several curves I have already plotted. Now I need to draw connections between SOME of the points on these curves (not all). But since I am already using the "line" function, and it already connects points (making curves), how can I draw the lines between points on separate curves? Is it possible at all in ggplot2?

[image: Here is what I have]
I need to connect all points that fall between 200 and 400 (on y scale) to each other (each one to each one), on this existing plot.
Is it possible? My code so far is like this:

```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(reshape2)

> trytidy <- melt(data = try, id="Cycle", variable.name="Concentration", value.name = "RFU")
> View(trytidy)
> ggplot(trytidy, aes(x=Cycle, y=RFU, colour=Concentration)) + 
      geom_line() + 
      geom_point(size=2.5) + 
      xlim(12,30)
```

Here is the link to data sample
[Data sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y27mDkB5cYo8XKvbWwOZD_uZivCzMVsqCi4KwLcCv-o/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You're looking for something along [these lines](https://twitter.com/lenkiefer/status/1003752511440814080)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Yes, and in my case I want to connect all points with all points, as long as the values fall between 200 and 400. The principle is the same as in the picture you linked - lines are plotted, and then points on separate lines connected. I would really appreciate it if you could point at the solution, where I can find one.

Comment: You need to map two groupings to two aesthetics, e.g. `color` and `group`, e.g. `ggplot(data.frame(x = rep(1:10, 5), y = rep(1:5, each = 10) * 1:10 + rnorm(50, sd = .3), l1 = rep(letters[1:5], each = 10), l2 = letters[rep(1:5, each = 10) + 1:10]), aes(x, y)) + geom_line(aes(group = l2)) + geom_point(aes(color = l1)) + geom_line(aes(color = l1))`

Comment: I see. Thanks for the suggestion. But in this case it does not connect all of the points within the range, it connects only some... I need something like a network, like this: https://www.data-imaginist.com/2017/ggraph-introduction-layouts/, but I would also like to keep the existing plotted curves in different colors, too.

Comment: Please include the sample data within the question itself.

Comment: @YuliaPanina That page is about plotting graphs (network-graphs, not plot-graphs). To take such an approach, you'd first need to create a graph. From there, you need to either plot the graph on the current plot, or plot the full plot from the graph. Both are probably doable, but as graphs don't inherently have a defined layout, it may take some work to close the gap. The subgraph you're asking for is K20, too, so even correctly plotted, it's still going to look like a bit of a hairball.

Comment: A simple[r] approach may be to generate a walk of the subgraph and plot it with `geom_path`.